# Meteor subscribe on event/render

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, publish-subscribe

is there a way to subscribe in meteor when an event triggers or a template is rendered? Im trying to get a message popup and subscribe to all usernames when this happens.

Tried:

```
Template.newMessage.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.subscribe("allUsernames");
}
```

And:

```
Template.layout.events({
    "click #new-message": function(e, t){
        $("#styledModal").modal();
        Meteor.subscribe("allUsernames");
    }
});
```

Neither work though, any way to do this or do I have to use a different route? Im using iron router

Comment: I would say that what you're trying to do should work. How does the Template provide the information and how do you include the data in your template. Can you update/extend your post ?

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to understand why you would wanna do subscribe is such a late state of the process?

I would recommand that u subscribe in the waitOn property in IronRouter.
If you use the waitOn property to subscribe to all users, within that route, you can just display them in the popup =)

1 of the 7 Meteor principles is:
Latency Compensation. On the client, use prefetching and model simulation to make it look like you have a zero-latency connection to the database.

source:
http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples

Hope this helps,
Alex

Comment: Sounds like you're a bit contradictory now. Just to be clear: subscribing to the data in the `waitOn` method in the iron router package does not prefetch the data, and thus does not contribute to any latency compensation.

Comment: I have a new message button in the navigation bar, when I click this I want to show a modal with a dropdown containing all the users usernames, I don't want to subscribe to this on every route.

Comment: So is there no way to subscribe on an event, I don't see why this sort of thing isn't possible

Comment: @theo3335796 You can subscribe to a publication anywhere in the code. I guess you have to show us more code in order for us to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it using Deps and Session (although your code should work too, maybe you have a problem with publications?).

In your main template rendered function put this:

```
Template.layout.rendered = function() {
    Session.set('getAllUsers',false);
    Deps.autorun(function () {
        if(Session.get('getAllUsers' == true)
            Meteor.subscribe('allUsernames');
    })
}
```

Then in the template that opens the user list:

```
Template.newMessage.rendered = function(){
    Session.set('getAllUsers',true); //this should trigger Deps.autorun and subscribe.
}
```

Comment: Use `Session.equals(key, value)` instead of `Session.get(key) == value` (can potentially result in fewer recomputations). However, using `Session` and `Deps.autorun` seems like an unnecessary complex way to do it.

Comment: Still not working, not sure what the issue is here, should I make a new post to update my code?

Comment: the problem was I am using selectize and it was loading before the subscription has completed making the dropdown empty, fixed now though